# no instance of overloaded function "stoi" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, int

I'm trying to write a function that takes 4 characters,with the first and third characters being numbers,and the second and fourth characters being operators,the function converts the the first and third characters into integers,and calculates the output based on the operator between them (or doesn't do that,if the operator stored in the fourth character has a higher priority).

This is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>



using namespace std;

string calculate(char ch1,char ch2,char ch3,char ch4);


int main() {
    int i = 1;
    string input = "4/1+1-2*2" ;
    string part;
    int leng;
    while(1){

        char cha1 = input[i - 1];
        char cha2 = input[i];
        char cha3 = input[i + 1];
        char cha4 = input[i + 2];
        part = calculate(cha1,cha2,cha3,cha4);
        if (part == "NULL") {
            i += 2;
}
        else{ input = input.replace((i-1),3,part); }
        leng = input.size();
        if (i == leng - 1) {
            i = 1;
        }
    }





}

string calculate(char ch1, char ch2, char ch3, char ch4){
    int in1;
    int in3;
    int result;
    string part;


    if (ch2 == '-') {
        if (ch4 == '*') {
            part = 'NULL';



        }
        else if (ch4 == '/') {
            part = "NULL";
        }
        else {
            in1 = stoi(ch1);
            in3 = stoi(ch3);
            result = in1 - in3;


            part = to_string(result);
        }

    }

    else if (ch2 == '+') {
        if (ch4 == '*') {
            part = "NULL";
        }
        else if (ch4 == '/') {
            part = "NULL";
        }
        else {
            in1 = stoi(ch1);
            in3 = stoi(ch3);
            result = in1 + in3;

            part = to_string(result);

        }
    }


    else if (ch2 == '*') {
        if (ch4 == '*') {
            part = "NULL";
        }
        else if (ch4 == '/') {
            part = "NULL";
        }
        else {
            in1 = stoi(ch1);
            in3 = stoi(ch3);
            result = in1 * in3;

            part = to_string(result);
        }
    }

    else if (ch2 == '/') {
        if (ch4 == '*') {
            part = "NULL";
        }
        else if (ch4 == '/') {
            part = "NULL";
        }
        else {
            in1 = stoi(ch1);
            in3 = stoi(ch3);
            result = in1 * in3;


            part = to_string(result);

        }
    }



    return part;
}
```

The program probably won't work as intended in it's current state,but I'll worry about that later,for now I want to deal with the `stoi()` function,because for every line that contains this function,I get the error in the title.

I want to know what I'm doing wrong,and what this error message exactly means to avoid getting it in the future.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stoi` expects a `std::string` as argument, but you are giving it a single `char`.

There is no direct conversion from `char` to `std::string`, so you need to be explicit about it:

```
stoi(string(1, ch1));
```

Here `string(1, ch1)` creates a string of length `1` containing only the character `ch1`.

Alternatively, if you are sure that `ch1` is a digit at that point (`stoi` will throw if it isn't) you can simply subtract `'0'`, since the digits are guaranteed to be correctly ordered in the character set:

```
ch1 - '0'
```

Or rather, you probably want to pass a `std::string` directly to your function, instead of multiple individual `char`s. You can use the [`.substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) member function to get substrings from a string.

Comment: [`.substr`] seemed like more work for one character at the time,now I know better,but yeah the first solution works for now,thank you!

Comment: @TheRiser I was expecting you to pass only one substring of length four to the function. Then you can access the four elements via index.

Comment: Now that you mention it,that was actually how I was doing it a while ago,but for one reason or another I changed to using 4 different chars instead,I think it was because I had other manipulations I wanted to do outside the ```calculate``` function with the 4 characters,but again,thank you,this should come in handy down the line,now that I have slightly better understanding with how to deal with chars and strings.

Answer (score 1):

std::stoi takes a std::string as its argument, but you are giving it a char.

You can directly convert char's to ints via a cast like this:

```
int num = ch1 - '0';
```

(You may want to write a function to do this, and use proper c++ style casts)

Or, covert the char to a string, or use strings to start with

Example:

```
int main() {
  char ch1 = '9';
  int in1 = ch1 - '0';
  std::cout << in1 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: There are no casts in this code. Don't know why the answer talks about them.